# Do I need to test my website on different monitors?

Tags: testing, web

I am developing a website that will be used by two sets of people.  One set will have 22 inch monitors, then other set have varying sizing but some are antique and some are pretty small.

My question is, is testing on one monitor under different resolutions (e.g. using Screenfly) the same as testing on several monitors of different sizes?  This question created some debate with my colleagues, but ultimately we don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to consider.

Device what is viewed on, a Mobile device, PC, etc. Mobile devices treat websites differently. Even if the resolution of the screen is to say 720p, browsers tend to display them as a 340px wide screen in portrait view.

Also besides screen size, you have to consider the resolution of the screen, You can have a 14-inch screen with a resolution of 1920x1080, or you could have a 40-inch screen with the same resolution.

So with all of these in mind, it becomes quite cumbersome to test for specific screen sizes. Programs like Screenfly and many others do a good job. But can hide some bugs and glitches. As they cannot copy the native support of the device, they mimic as well as they can. If your website is simple, it should do fine if you have followed responsive design practices. However if it JavaScript heavy website it could fail to display potential problems.

So in conclusion. No, Screenfly is not 100% guaranty there will be no bugs on the actual device. The best solution would be to test on actual devices of varying size.